# Overriding functions imported by a subsequent import?

Tags: python, import, monkeypatching

For a project, I need to substitute a function from a module. I would like to achieve this by the following minimal example

In `mod.py` the original function is defined,

```
def f():
    print("mod.py")
```

which should be overridden by `f2` in `mod2.py`,

```
import sys

def f2():
    print("mod2.py")

sys.modules["mod"].f = f2
```

In `main.py` I first load the original function, which I immediately patch

```
from mod import f
import mod2

f()  # I'm expecting "mod2.py", but get "mod.py" instead
```

It seems, that the function definition of `f` in the `__main__`'s globals() is a not a reference to `sys.modules["mod"].f`, which I was hoping.

If in `main.py` I import the module in which `f` is defined, instead `f` itself, I can patch it

```
import mod
import mod2

print(mod.f())  # patched from mod2
```

But I'd like to find a solution which works both imports in `main.py` — the import of the whole module (`import mod`) and the function itself (`from mod import f`).

I also tried to somehow modify the `locals()` from the parent frame via `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals` but this seems doesn't work as well and would feel hacky, if I'd find a solution like this, which would do what I want.

Is this in principle possible with the way Python handles `import`s?

Comment: *"It seems, that the function definition of f in the `__main__`'s globals() is a not a reference to `sys.modules["mod"].f`, which i was hoping"* -- correct, references are to objects, not to other names.  It is a reference to the function to which it points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good way to monkey-patch the function in `mod.py` so that it will affect any further imports of `mod` after an `import mod2`. This works because modules are cached in `sys.modules` — but you don't need to explicitly reference that if you do things as shown.

`mod.py`:

```
def f():
    print("mod.py")
```

`mod2.py`:

```
import mod

def f2():
    print("mod2.py")

# Monkey-patch `mod` module.
mod.f = f2
```

`main.py`:

```
import mod
import mod2  # Importing this applies the patch to the `mod` module.

mod.f()  # Prints -> mod2.py
```

Answer (score 2):

`from mod import f` takes the object referenced by `mod.f` and adds a binding to a new variable called `f` in the current module. The object now has at least two references, `mod.f` and `f`. If `mod.f` is reassigned, the original function object reference count is decremented by 1, but it is still referenced by the local `f` and so is still the object used when anybody dereferences `f`.

You could have a module that knows what monkey patching you want to do and have it import mod and mod2. Then import that module first. In fact, `mod2.py` could `import mod`. Its all rather fragile because users of your code need to know to be careful of the order in which things are imported.

And its a good idea not to `from mod import f`. Just `import mod` and do `mod.f` whenever you want to use it. In that case, you don't have a different reference to the function and the patching works.

Answer (score 1):

**mod.py**

```
def f():
    print("original")

def other():
    print("other in mod")
```

**mod2.py**

```
from mod import *
def f():
    print("override")
```

****main**.py**

```
#all of mod is in mod2, no need to import mod unless you need the original f()
import mod2
#if you do need the original f()
from mod import f

f() #original
mod2.f() #override
mod2.other() #other in mod
```

Overwriting all of this stuff in a procedural way is all fine and dandy, but it may be more helpful to use class inheritance.

```
class Mod:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        
    def f(self, data):
        #do something with data
        data.reverse()
        
        print(f'in Mod {data}')
        

class Mod2(Mod):
    def __init__(self):
        Mod.__init__(self)
        
    def f(self, data, skip=False):
        if not skip:
            #example of doing something that is not included in original f()
            data.pop(0)
            
            print(f'in Mod2 {data}')
            
        super().f(data) #call the original f() that this f() overrides


m2 = Mod2()

m2.f([11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
#in Mod2 [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
#in Mod [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

m2.f([11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], True)
#in Mod [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```